# Trying to make images load & appear sequentially in Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have spent 2 days reading every bit of code i can find on this and cant find the solution and apply it to my situation.  I hope someone can help.

I have a series of products/boxes (that contain images, words, etc) that i dynamically load into an isotope container using php (from a db).  Each product/box is it's own li in an ul isotope box.

I want the overall isotope container to be 3 columns wide (unless resizing occurs).

My problem is that on page load, all boxes are intitially loaded in just 1 column (which takes a long time as each image has to be loaded) until all boxes are loaded (ie all images are loaded) and then the isotope container can layout everything.

The user has to wait ages so i want each box to load into the container sequentially filling up row 1 (column 1, then column 2, then column 3), then proceed to filling up row 2 (column 1,etc) and so on so that boxes/products can be loading below the page fold unbenkownst to the user.  I am trying also therefore to use imagesLoaded.  Nothing i do works.

There are 3 code components - 1. CSS, 2. PHP/HTML, 3. JS . mine is below:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  
 var $container = $('#filter-container');
 $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.isotope({
   itemSelector: 'li',
   filter: '*',
   resizable: false,
   columnWidth: 300,
   animationEngine: 'best-available'
  });
  
  var $tour = $('#filter-container.li');
  $container.append($tour).isotope('appended',$tour);
 });
 
  
 // filter buttons
  
 $('#filter-buttons a').click(function(){
 
  // select current
  var $optionSet = $(this).parents('#filter-buttons');
     $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
    
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
 });
   
   //##########################################
 // Resize event
 //##########################################
 
 $(window).resize(function() {
  
  var w = $(window).width();
  //console.log(w);
 
  $container_home.isotope('reLayout');
 
 }).trigger("resize");
  
});
```

```css
#filter-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../img/filter.png) no-repeat top center;
  height: 47px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#filter-buttons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#filter-buttons li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 47px;
  color: #cb5432;
}
#filter-buttons li .selected {
  background: url(../img/filter-arrow.png) no-repeat center top;
}
.cf:after,
.cf:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cf {
  zoom: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#filter-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(../img/filter.png) no-repeat top center;
  height: 47px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#filter-buttons li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#filter-buttons li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 47px;
  color: #cb5432;
}
#filter-buttons li .selected {
  background: url(../img/filter-arrow.png) no-repeat center top;
}
.cf:after,
.cf:before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cf {
  zoom: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    top: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: right;
}  
.ribbon span {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 115px;
    display: block;
    background: #79A70A;
    background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: -26px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
/*RAF */
div .raf {
    width: 40px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 20%;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    background-image: url("//eternalcitytours.com/assets/ico/android-icon-36x36.png");
}
.feature {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: -65px;
  list-style-type:none
}
.feature li {
  position: relative;
  background: #f3e4c8;
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.feature li .thumb {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 280px;
}
.feature li .thumb img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.feature li .caption {
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.feature li a{
  color: #cb5432;
}
.feature li .thumb {
  position: relative;
}
.feature li .thumb .date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 110px;
  display: block;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 46px;
  background: #f3e4c8;
  float: left;
  font-family: mensch;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.feature li .thumb .date span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="filter-buttons">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All Tours | </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Top">Top Tours | </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Christian">Christian Tours | </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".Art">Art Tours | </a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".Romance">Romance Tours | </a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".Food">Food Tours | </a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".Day">Day Trips | </a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".Kids">Kids</a></li>
   </ul>
  <!-- Filter container -->
    <ul id="filter-container" class="feature cf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EventReservation">
        <?php 
    $tcount=count($tours);
    $tcount=$tcount-1;
    for($i=0; $i<=$tcount;$i++){
     echo "
     <li class=\"".$tours[$i]['location']."\">
          <a href=\"".$tours[$i]['nav_url']."\"><div class=\"ribbon\"><span>From € ".$tours[$i]['action']."</span></div></a>
                            <a href=\"".$tours[$i]['nav_url']."\" class=\"thumb\">".$tours[$i]['img']."
       <div class=\"date\"><div class=\"raf\"></div></div>
       </a>
                            <h4 class=\"tour_title\" itemprop=\"name\">".$tours[$i]['title']."</h4>
                            <div class=\"caption\" itemprop=\"description\">".$tours[$i]['blurb']."</div>
       <p><a href=\"".$tours[$i]['nav_url']."\" title=\"".$tours[$i]['title']."\" class=\"tours btn btn-primary\" itemprop=\"url\" role=\"button\">View Tour &rarr;</a></p>
                    </li>
     ";
    }?>
    </ul><!-- ENDS Filter container -->
```

Can anyone help me work out how to get each product/tour/box load sequentially along each row as the page loads??  a live example of the page as it is now is at [here](https://eternalcitytours.com/en/2/Christian-Pilgrim-Tours-Of-Rome-Italy)

Answer (score 0):

Right - solved it.

The overall issue is that i had my first line of JS code as

```
$(window).load( function() {
```

This basically means the page has to load before it does anything else which is obviously the exact opposite of what i wanted.

Then to make the images/boxes/products load sequentially along each row, my code then continued:

```
var $container = $('#filter-container').isotope({
        itemSelector: 'li',
        filter: '*',
        resizable: false,
        columnWidth: 'li',
        animationEngine: 'best-available'
    });

    $container.imagesLoaded().progress( function(){
        $container.isotope('layout');
    });
```

hope that helps someone else.